# Spring Boot 2.x doesn't scan application.properties when I specify spring.config.location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I just playing around with Spring Boot 2.0.4 and I notice this today. Not sure that I missed something or not. Please help me to check.

**Spring Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

**application.properties** (located in src/main/resources)

```
server.port=8088
```

start the project using Intellij

```
2018-08-17 12:11:05 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
```

start the project using java command line:

```
java -jar sample.jar --spring.config.location=D:\config\ --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

The application is not using the configured port

```
2018-08-17 11:25:25 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

It's look like Spring Boot 2.0 ignored the default properties file (note: this configuration only in applications.properties no where else, so it won't be overlapped by another configuration files)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You specify `spring.config.location` to start the uber-jar and from Spring Boot 2, specifying this argument replaces the default locations used by Spring as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

> When custom config locations are configured by using
>   `spring.config.location`, they replace the default locations. For
>   example, if `spring.config.location` is configured with the value
>   `classpath:/custom-config/`,`file:./custom-config/`, the search order
>   becomes the following:
>
> 1. `file:./custom-config/`
> 2. `classpath:custom-config/`

So I think that you have to explicitly add the `application.properties` in `spring.config.location` :

```
--spring.config.location=D:\config\,classpath:\application.properties
```

Or as alternative use `spring.config.additional-location` such as `--spring.config.additional-location=D:\config\`  instead of `spring.config.location` that will add rather than replace locations [as stated by the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) :

> Alternatively, when custom config locations are configured by using
>   spring.config.additional-location, they are used in addition to the
>   default locations.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx this resolved my issue. It's working fine in Spring Boot 1.4 but I think they change it in Spring Boot 2. Many thanks

Comment: You are welcome :) You are right: the default behavior changed from Spring Boot 2.  And `spring.config.additional-location` was introduced in SB 2 to keep a way to have the same behavior.

Comment: yes, but I don't believe this solution will allow you to go outside of root of project.  it restricts you to files only under the root of the project.  right?

Answer (score 0):

You said you put your config file in src/main/resource(s) - but your command line tells spring to look in d:\config.  Did you put a copy of the file there?

Comment: I have 2 another properties files (application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties) for some configuration I want to expose to the users. If I put the config there it works but it also work if I put it in application.properties. According to the document any application-{profile}.properties will override application.properties if it has a same name.